# In a standalone google-apps-script project, where would the spreadsheet functions be stored?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Where the Code.gs file is bound to the spreadsheet, user-defined functions are stored there along with any other functions like event handlers.

In a standalone project, would Code.gs hold user-defined functions or is there some other mechanism which makes functions defined in a standalone project visible to the spreadsheet that uses it?

Comment: In container bound scripts within the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

- You want to use a function in the standalone script as a custom function.

If my understanding is correct, unfortunately, the function in the standalone script cannot be directly used as the custom function for Spreadsheet. So as a workaround, how about using the standalone script as a library? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Sample situation:

The sample situation is as follows.

- Standalone script has a function of `myFunction()`. This is used as a library. The sample library name is "SampleLib". The sample script is as follows.

  ```
  function myFunction(e) {
    return "Done: " + e;
  }
  ```
- Container-bound script of Spreadsheet has a function of `CustomFunction()`. The sample script is as follows. Before you use this script, please install above library.

  ```
  function CustomFunction(e) {
    return SampleLib.myFunction(e);
  }
  ```

  - After the library is installed in the bound script, when `=CustomFunction("sample")` is put in a cell, `Done: sample` is returned. By this, it is found that `myFunction()` of the library of "SampleLib" is used.

#### Note:

- As another workaround, I think that Web Apps can be also used. But the process cost will be higher than that of the library.

#### Reference:

- [Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)

If this workaround was not the result you want, I apologize.